# FX Modeling references

Tags: fx, reference-request, best-practices

I would like to have some sugestions of reference books on FX modeling with strong mathematical approach, preferably combined with market pratictioner quant perspective.

All sugesting are welcome! Many thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Personally, I prefer the book [Foreign Exchange Option Pricing](https://www.amazon.ca/Foreign-Exchange-Option-Pricing-Practitioners/dp/0470683686) by Iain Clark and the book [FX Options and Smile Risk](https://www.amazon.ca/Options-Smile-Risk-Wiley-Finance-ebook/dp/B003AU7DXO) by Antonio Castagna. The book [FX Options and Structured Products](https://www.amazon.ca/Options-Structured-Products-Uwe-Wystup/dp/0470011459) by Uwe Wystup is also good.